# Remove duplicates in Long array

Tags: java, arrays

I have two Long array elements and both have some values

```
Long[] firstArray = new Long[10];
Long[] secondArray = new Long[25];
```

Both the array may or may not be equal in size.

```
firstArray[0] = new Long("1"); 
firstArray[1] = new Long("2"); 
firstArray[2] = new Long("3"); 

secondArray [0] = new Long("2"); 
secondArray [1] = new Long("3");
```

I want to compare the `secondArray` with `firstArray` and create a new `thirdArray` with the values which are not in `secondArray`.

In the above example the `thirdArray` will have only `1`

Comment: Why arrays? Why not collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution would be to convert both of your arrays to List and use [`removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-):

```
Long[] firstArray = new Long[10];
Long[] secondArray = new Long[25];

firstArray[0] = new Long("1"); 
firstArray[1] = new Long("2"); 
firstArray[2] = new Long("3"); 

secondArray [0] = new Long("2"); 
secondArray [1] = new Long("3"); 

List<Long> first = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(firstArray));
List<Long> second = Arrays.asList(secondArray);

first.removeAll(second);

Long[] thirdArray = first.toArray(new Long[first.size()]);
```

Comment: @Tunaki but your code is removing from first, not second.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient to dump one of the arrays into the set, so you can perform fast search:

```
Set<Long> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(second));
```

After that you can use:

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(first));
list.removeAll(set);
return list.toArray(new Long[list.size()]);
```

Or simpler in Java-8:

```
return Stream.of(first).filter(e -> !set.contains(e)).toArray(Long[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep track of the amounts of repeating elements, you could use a `Map<Long, Long>`.

Build the map (either a simple `for` or with `stream()` and `groupingBy()`), then iterate over the second array and decrease the count for each key, and then iterate over map's pairs and build the array again.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8:

```
Set<Long> set = Stream.of(secondArray).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Long[] thirdArray = Stream.of(firstArray).filter(e -> !set.contains(e)).toArray(Long[]::new);
```